# CSS Error parsing JavaFX for Pane Background

Tags: css, javafx, linear-gradients, pane

I am having a newbie problem detecting why can't I set a linear gradient as a background for my Pane.
When I set the background like this :

```
pane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: linear-gradient(to right,#000000 0%,#d70db2 12%,#000000 24%,#d70db2 41%, #d70db2 59%,#000000 76%,#d70db2 88%,#000000 100%)");
```

works perfectly. But if I try to set it like this :

```
pane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: " +  new LinearGradient(0,0,1,0,false,CycleMethod.NO_CYCLE,new Stop(1, Color.RED),new Stop(1,Color.MAGENTA)));
```

or like this :

```
private Stop stop1 = new Stop(0, Color.MAGENTA);
private Stop stop2 = new Stop(1, Color.RED);
private Stop[] stops = new Stop[]{stop1, stop2}; //{stop1,stop2,stop3,stop4,stop5,stop6,stop7,stop8};
private LinearGradient lg = new LinearGradient(0,0,1,0,true,CycleMethod.NO_CYCLE,stops);


pane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: " + lg );
```

I am getting the following CSS Error :

```
WARNING: CSS Error parsing '*{-fx-background-color: linear-gradient(from 0.0% 0.0% to 100.0% 0.0%, 0xff00ffff 0.0%, 0xff0000ff 100.0%)}: Unexpected token '0xff' at [1,71]
```

The specific line [1,71] is the position of the first color.

Comment: The `toString()` method of `LinearGradient` is not designed to be valid CSS. (In particular, as you note, the colors are specified differently.) You can't mix-and-match setting the style with creating a `LinearGradient` object like this. Either do this in CSS, or use your `LinearGradient` instance to create a `BackgroundFill` and pass it to `pane.setBackground(...)`.

Comment: @noxus010 I suggest that you post the code for the working solution as a self-answer and mark it as correct when the system allows you to do so.